# Exception on apache cxf when calling JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create() (in maven project)

Tags: java, cxf

I wrote  a Client that uses a Webservice. 
Works well in a seperate project. But when I try to use it in my maven project, it fails.
The dependencies are correct:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- Jetty is needed if you're are not using the CXFServlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

But the error seems to occur calling this method:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create();
```

This is what I get:

```
    10.06.2010 12:50:59 org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://tempuri.org/}BMWebServiceSoapService from class net.myClassPath.BMWebServiceSoap
2010-06-10 12:51:00.992::WARN:  Nested in org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/extensions/soap12/SOAP12Address:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/extensions/soap12/SOAP12Address
```

Does anyone have a clue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a maven dependncy:tree or similar.   It LOOKS like you are picking up an old or bad version of wsdl4j.

Dan

Comment: This is what I get:
 
(wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5.1)

Don't really know what that means though :-/

Comment: Just figured it out. Had to exclude the 1.5.1 to make it use 1.6.2
Thanks!